# Using ReadableStream as HTML <audio> source

Tags: reactjs, audio-streaming

`const response = await fetch(url, {headers});`

Where `response?.body` is a ReadableStream returned by the API.
Is there any chance to convert somehow this ReadableStream to a source for the `<audio>` tag?

Comment: presumably if you already know what the url is for your audio tag, can't you just do `<audio src={url} />` unless you are using something specific in headers to return the correct file?

Comment: Hi, the link is secured with JWT and I can't send that header through link.

Comment: You need to load (or copy) the `response?.body` data values into an **Array**, then you can feed that into the audio `.src` as a blob using `createObjectURL`.

Comment: That won't work for a ReadableStream @VC.One. Alpár will need to create a reader from the body and then send each chunk to an AudioContext. I'll test it out and write up an answer once i've figured it out

Comment: @kano do you have an example of this you could pull up quickly?